# Has any congressperson ever been a victim of discrimination while in office?

Tags: united-states, congress, racism, discrimination, nationalism

From the *U.S. Equal Employment Opportunity Commission*'s web page [*Immigrants' Employment Rights Under Federal Anti-Discrimination Laws*](https://www.eeoc.gov/eeoc/publications/immigrants-facts.cfm):

> **Harassment Based on National Origin**
>   Ethnic slurs and other verbal or physical conduct because of nationality are illegal if they are severe or pervasive and create an intimidating, hostile or offensive working environment, interfere with work performance, or negatively affect job opportunities. Examples of potentially unlawful conduct include insults, taunting, or ethnic epithets, such as making fun of a person's foreign accent **or comments like, "Go back to where you came from, "** whether made by supervisors or by co-workers.

Has any acting, (*i.e.* while in office), congressperson ever been a victim of discrimination under the Laws outlined by the EEOC above?

Comment: A possible recent application might be a certain [infamous tweet](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1150381395078000643).

Comment: Are you asking if they've ever been a victim where action was taken by Congress's equivalent of HR? Or are you asking if they've ever been a victim just under the quoted example? If it's the latter, the fact that you linked the president's tweet makes it look like you already know the answer and aren't actually asking a question.

Comment: There were thousands of congressmen and women over time. I would be very much surprised if this wasn't the case.

Comment: This maybe a question for law.SE (as to whether EEOC's rules apply to elected members of Congress) or for history.  But members of Congress are the government rather than employees of the government.  While they are compensated for their service, they cannot be fired by anyone in the government.  Obviously they can lose an election, but that's not being fired.  That's losing the privilege of being in a position of power.  As long as no one can fire them, it's hard to argue that any law meant to address the power imbalance in an employment situation applies to them.

Comment: @Giter, That's *a* possible instance, but the Q. is about the general case, not any specific instance as such.

Comment: @grovkin, A democratic republic's Congress is employed by the people, with [salaries and various benefits](https://www.thoughtco.com/salaries-and-benefits-of-congress-members-3322282).  It's true that no ***one*** person can fire a member of congress, but members can [and have been expelled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_representatives_expelled,_censured,_or_reprimanded#Expelled_Representatives) by a group, though it'd be more usual for malfeasant members to [resign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resignation_from_the_United_States_Senate).

Comment: I want to point out that there's a difference between *harassment*, which the citation is about and generally refers to **communication**, and *discrimination*, which the question is about and generally refers to **decisions**.  It's harassment to say "go back where you came from", and discrimination to reject a job applicant.  Some things can be both, but you need to clarify what you're asking about here.

Comment: Closing really? Maybe one should limit the question to everything before June 2019 and one would probably still get lots and lots of cases. Voted for reopen.

Comment: @Bobson, Re *harassment* vs *discrimination*:  in my view, harassment based on national origin is *both*.  Please elaborate if I seem to be missing some useful distinction.

Comment: @agc compensation alone does not create an employer/employee relationship.  For example, anyone going to a doctor, and paying cash, compensates the doctor.  But the doctor would not be considered a patient's employee for the purposes of any law.

Answer (score 1):

The law in question and the EEOC that enforces it concern only discrimination and harassment in the workplace.  This law does not protect elected Congressional representatives in their congressional workplace.

The prohibition against harassment is not explicit in the [statute](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/chapter-21/subchapter-VI), known as Title VII of the Civil Rights Act of 1964.  Harassment is the subject of EEOC regulation at [29 CFR 1606.8](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/29/1606.8):

> The Commission has consistently held that harassment on the basis of national origin is a violation of title VII. An employer has an affirmative duty to maintain a working environment free of harassment on the basis of national origin.

However, at [29 CFR 1601.2](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/29/1601.2), the definition of *employer* is explicitly taken from title VII, [where the definition of *employer* at [42 USC 2000e(b) explicitly excludes the United States](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/2000e#b).

> (b) The term “employer” means a person engaged in an industry affecting commerce who has fifteen or more employees for each working day in each of twenty or more calendar weeks in the current or preceding calendar year, and any agent of such a person, **but such term does not include (1) the United States,** [or ...]

There is another section concerning employment by the federal government that could be relevant, found at [42 USC 2000e-16](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/2000e-16).  It brings within the scope of the act employment (bullet list formatting added):

> - in military departments as defined in section 102 of title 5,
> - in executive agencies as defined in section 105 of title 5 (including employees and applicants for employment who are paid from nonappropriated funds),
> - in the United States Postal Service and the Postal Regulatory Commission,
> - in those units of the Government of the District of Columbia having positions in the competitive service, and
> - in those units of the judicial branch of the Federal Government having positions in the competitive service,
> - in the Smithsonian Institution, and
> - in the Government Publishing Office, the Government Accountability Office, and the Library of Congress

None of this would extend the protections of this law to an elected representative in congress.

Accordingly, congressional representatives *do not have an employer,* at least for the EEOC's purposes, so they do not enjoy its protection.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer.  I'm still a bit foggy on details.  If any of the following seem relevant to the present Q., this answer leaves the layman wondering stuff like: Under these definitions, can a person be an employee *without* an employer?   Can an employee harass an employer?  Can a co-worker harass another co-worker?  Do the words *"any agent of"* apply to members of Congress?  Can members of Congress harass their staff?

Comment: (Note: that's not my downvote.)

Comment: @agc *employee* is also defined at [42 USC 2000e(f)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/2000e#b): "(f) The term “employee” means an individual employed by an employer, ...."  There are several exceptions, but since members of congress do not have an employer under the Title VII definition, they are not employees.  In other words, under this definition, a person *cannot* be an employee without an employer.  It doesn't matter whether congressional representatives are "agents of" the US under this law because the US is explicitly excluded.

Comment: @agc The other questions in your comment are beyond the scope of this question, so it would not be appropriate to address them in the answer, but I note that congressional staff are protected from discrimination by the house and senate rules.  There are also criminal laws that prohibit various forms of harassment and intimidation, which I looked at while I was preparing this answer, but after re-reading the tweets I don't think they apply here.  On top of that, the tweets are protected by the first amendment as political speech, which probably outweighs the harassment and intimidation.

Comment: @agc I also note that the question in the title is far broader than that in the body, and can be unequivocally answered in the affirmative.  The house of representatives' own website has a [page](https://history.house.gov/Exhibitions-and-Publications/BAIC/Historical-Essays/Keeping-the-Faith/Crafting-Institutional-Identity/) in its history section that begins "Across the decades, African-American Members encountered institutional racism and segregation on Capitol Hill."

Comment: Thanks.  Please incorporate that affirmative HR institutional racism data, and I'll mark this as answered.  (The tweets are interesting, but are also merely topical.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96541/discussion-between-phoog-and-agc).